# Escaping -- (double dash)

Tags: sql-server-ce

In SQL CE if I am inserting a string (includes newlines)

```
N'hello
--Janet'
```

It is treated as an unterminated string followed by a comment
Is there a way to escape the double dash?
(this problem refers to cqlcecmd40 as found at http://sqlcecmd.codeplex.com)

Comment: Why do you need to escape it?

Comment: I realize this is probably a problem with my parser, I'm just wondering if anyone has an idea on how this might be done

Comment: The parser seems to not continue the string across linebreaks, when it should.

Comment: Why are you inserting data as part of your SQL?

Comment: I had harvested my data from SQL Server using this tool http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/

It worked very well but it created this problem. I have since submitted a patch to prevent the tool from creating these strings

Comment: OK, your Exportsqlce patch would probably solve the issue, or?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being part of a string it needs no escaping.

`--` is only interpreted as the start of a comment *outside* of strings.

---

Update (after question was revised):

You can do the following to achieve the same effect:

```
N'hello' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + '--Janet'
```

Comment: do you have a citation for the spec that indicates this? (documenting tool failure)

Comment: @lostinplace - What tool failure? And why do you need citation for something you can test in a couple of minutes?

Comment: I'm using a library that should parse emails into sql yet it fails on double hyphens (content)

Comment: Just because I can test and prove it doesn't mean the next guy can, and it also helps me submit a bug report

Comment: @lostinplace - Looks like a bug in the library. As far as SQL is concerned, `--` within a string is just part of the string.

Comment: @lostinplace - No spec would put a exception like that anywhere. I can point you to any description of NVARCHAR that you like, but non will say anything about `--` being treated as a normal pair of characters in such a field... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx